# When can I grant advantage/impose disadvantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, advantage-and-disadvantage

As a DM I wonder, what conditions if any must be met to impose an advantage or disadvantage on a roll.

Example - the PC's are tracking a wolf, but the entire party wandered over the tracks several times before noticing them, disadvantage survival (tracking)?

Example - the PC's have had experience handling a similar magical item, they find an item and want to determine if it is evil/good/what effect it may have. Advantage arcana?

Just wondering what is RAW on granting advantage for checks, or if I have accidentally been home brewing certain situations.

Comment: Just a note: It is not homebrew to act like a DM in 5th edition.  The design intent was to go more for "rulings over rules" with a less intense focus on "rules and rules lawyering" in order to keep the game flowing and the fun active.  Your judgment is a key element to your table's game.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As far as the rules are concerned, you can give advantage or disadvantage whenever you deem it appropriate.

> The DM can
>   also decide that circumstances influence a roll in one
>   direction or the other and grant advantage or impose
>   disadvantage as a result.

The DMG gives some more guidance on *when* you might deem it appropriate in the section titled Advantage and Disadvantage on page 239.